# linking data by semantic core in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 prices, I need to join it by goods. But the description of goods may be slightly different.
One of many examples:

```
metal-ceramic products gost 22 456-22mm
metal-ceramic prod. gost 22 456-22mm
```

In fact, this is one and the same.Just  word products has been reduced. Of course R will not link this item, it will think that it is different names.
What can be done to make R "see" that it's the same thing, it's cognates
Please help.
Number of titles is enormous

Comment: Search for "fuzzy join."